# Multiple levels of aggregation

Tags: pyspark

I have a pyspark.sql.Dataframe, of the form

```
[[patient1, visit1, code1],
 [patient1, visit1, code2],
 [patient1, visit2, code3],
 [patient1, visit2, code4]]
```

I'm trying to turn it into another Dataframe, using structs:

```
[[patient1, [visit1, [code1, code2],
             visit2, [code3, code4]]]
```

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming column names - `patient`, `visit`, `code` - you can do:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

res=(df
    .groupBy(
        f.col('patient'),
        f.col('visit')
    )
    .agg(
        f.collect_list(f.col('code')).alias('code')
    )
    .select(
        f.col('patient'), 
        f.struct('visit', 'code').alias('_merged')
    )
    .groupBy(
        f.col('patient')
    ).agg(
        f.collect_list(f.col('_merged')).alias('_merged')
    )
)
```

Comment: Running this, I got: `cannot resolve 'arrays_zip(\`visit\`, \`code\`)' due to data type mismatch: argument 1 requires array type, however, '\`visit\`' is of string type`. But this gave me the right idea: first agg the codes, then agg the visits. My solution: `res = df.groupby('patient', 'visit').agg(F.collect_list('code').alias('codes')).groupby('patient').agg(F.collect_list(F.struct('visit', 'codes')).alias('history'))`

Comment: I mean - as long as it works :) you just need to merge 2 columns together - one string, one collected list. Then ```collect_list``` the result- that's the idea.

Comment: I added that piece to my answer